# Camel-Kafka ConsumerCount drops to 1 (default) from the defined value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Iam using kafka consumer in our application integrated with Camel(Camel-Kafka). We consume the messages and send the data to the server for processing.
There is one topic "XYZ" defined with 30 partitions and I have assgined 15 as consumer count on each consumer node (total 2 instances)'

**CamelConsumer Configuration**

```
kafka.consumersCount=15
kafka.consumerStreams=15
```

I see from the logs that when the consumer starts, there are 15 consumer threads (lets say on 1 node), which is good as configured.

```
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 0 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #3 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 1 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 2 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 3 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 4 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 5 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #8 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 6 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #9 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 7 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #10 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 8 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #11 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 9 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #12 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 10 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 11 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #14 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 12 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #15 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 13 to topic XYZ
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #16 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 14 to topic XYZ
```

If server stops responding due to network issue or any other scenario when the server is unavailable.
All the kafka consumers starts unsubscribing which is again an expected behavior (so far good)

**Note:** We have also define the Camel `ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy` which does a health check call on the server before sending the consumed message.

Once the server is back and available, i see that not all 15 consumer threads are active, but only 1.
From the logs below, I observe that its getting subscribed and unsubscribed one by one and finally the application runs with only a single consumer count.

```
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #17 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 0 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [ListOfDefinedServers]
check.crcs = true
client.id = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = XYZ-GroupId-12345
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 5000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 40000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = SSL
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
ssl.key.password = [hidden]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = cert.jks
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = cert.jks
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #17 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 0 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #18 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 1 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #18 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 1 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #19 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 2 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #19 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 2 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #20 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 3 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #20 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 3 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #21 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 4 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #21 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 4 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #22 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 5 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #22 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 5 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #23 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 6 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #23 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 6 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #24 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 7 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #24 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 7 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #25 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 8 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #25 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 8 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #26 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 9 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #26 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 9 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #27 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 10 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #27 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 10 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #28 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 11 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #28 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 11 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #29 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 12 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #29 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 12 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #30 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 13 to topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #30 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:351)] Unsubscribing XYZ-Thread 13 from topic XYZ
INFO  [kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig(logAll:238)] ConsumerConfig values: Prints all the consumer config values defined/undefined

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:222)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 14 to topic XYZ

INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(info:341)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-30, groupId=XYZ-GroupId-12345] Discovered group coordinator servername (id: 2147482644 rack: null)
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(info:341)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-30, groupId=XYZ-GroupId-12345] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(info:336)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-30, groupId=XYZ-GroupId-12345] (Re-)joining group
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator(info:341)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-30, groupId=XYZ-GroupId-12345] Successfully joined group with generation 1
INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator(info:341)] [Consumer clientId=consumer-30, groupId=XYZ-GroupId-12345] Setting newly assigned partitions [XYZ-17, XYZ-19, XYZ-13, XYZ-15, XYZ-25, XYZ-27, XYZ-21, XYZ-23, XYZ-1, XYZ-3, XYZ-28, XYZ-9, XYZ-11, XYZ-5, XYZ-7, XYZ-16, XYZ-18, XYZ-12, XYZ-14, XYZ-24, XYZ-26, XYZ-20, XYZ-22, XYZ-0, XYZ-2, XYZ-29, XYZ-8, XYZ-10, XYZ-4, XYZ-6]
```

Any idea why is camel not running with the defined consumer count, rather runs with only a single consumer. This affects the processing speed of the consumer application when the load is more.

Any help or suggestion what is going wrong here ?

I expect 15 consumer threads running after the failure which is as defined in the camel kafka config.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? And have you tried to upgrade to a newer version

Comment: I was using camel 2.22.0, upgraded to 2.24.2. Still see the same issue.

Comment: What do you see in the logs if you use DEBUG logging level for camel-kafka ?

Comment: @ClausIbsen
I do see that just before the last thread (15), 
The ThrottlingRoutePolicy is starting
`DEBUG Camel (camel-1) thread #30 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:398)] Closing XYZ-Thread 13
    DEBUG Timer-0 [apache.camel.impl.ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy(resumeOrStartConsumer:154)] Started consumer Consumer[]`

Comment: `INFO  Camel (camel-1) thread #31 - KafkaConsumer[XYZ] [camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer(doRun:247)] Subscribing XYZ-Thread 14 to topic XYZ
DEBUG Timer-0 [apache.camel.impl.ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy(logState:281)] State closed, failures 0`

Comment: This means that, the ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy is resuming at the last thread, not sure why is it so, But I ideally It should have been resumed at the start when all the threads start subscribing.

Comment: Try without that throttling policy

Comment: @Clauslben,I tried removing the throttling policy, but i get into number of other issues. I have reproduced the actual issue. Hope this help you to see the issue

https://github.com/srikant-mvs/SimpleRestInterface : Dummy Server application listening to endpoints
https://github.com/srikant-mvs/SimpleCamelKafkaProducer : Send message to kafka
https://github.com/srikant-mvs/SimpleCamelKafkaConsumer : Consumer application where the issue exists

Comment: @Clauslben How to retry without throttlingRoutePolicy, is there an alternative approach in camel ?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue.

Setup is as follows :

- Spring-boot : 2.2.x
- Camel version : 2.24.1
- Topic has 3 partitions.

  - kafka.consumersCount=3 (1 per partition)
  - kafka.consumersStreams= 10 [default value]
- ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy - open the circuit if the exception occurs.

In camel-kafka component , KafkaConsumer does not implement Suspendable interface even though it implements SuspendableService interface. So the consumer needs to be shutdown and started to mimic a suspend/resume functionality.

So this what happens when you openCircuit() and closeCircuit()

- KafkaConsumer (Singleton) bean uses AtomicBoolean fields – **started, starting, stopping, stopped, suspending, suspended, shuttingdown, shutdown** to keep track of its current state.

1. Once the application’s camel route is stated , then state becomes : KafkaConsumer { **started=true**, starting = false, stopping = false, stopped = false, shutdown = false }
2. When the circuit is open, then the state is : KafkaConsumer { started=false, starting= false, stopping=false, **stopped=true**, shutdown = false }
3. When the circuit close is initiated , the KafkaConsumer state is still :  **stopped=true** and the kafka consumer startup(resume) process is initiated.

KafkaConsumer:

```
  doStart(){
      // create executor with worker thread count = consumerStreams 
      for (int i = 0; i < endpoint.getConfiguration().getConsumersCount(); i++) {
           KafkaFetchRecords task = new KafkaFetchRecords(topic, pattern, i + "", getProps());
           // pre-initialize task during startup so if there is any error we have it thrown asap
           task.preInit();
           executor.submit(task);  
           tasks.add(task);
      }    
  }
```

KafkaFetchRecords :

```
doRun(){
   clientConsumer.subscribe(topic);
   while( isRunAllowed() && !reConnect && !isStoppingOrStopped() && !isSuspendingOrSuspended()){
      clientConsumer.poll();
   }
   clientConsumer.unsubscribe(topic) 
}
```

- Since the executor.submit(), triggers the doRun() without any delay, the KafkaConsumer state is still **stopped**, the while loop is skipped and the kafka consumer client ends unsubscribing from the topic.
- Once the doStart()'s for loop completes, the KafkaConsumer's state is marked as **stopped = false , started = true**
- so for the very last (KafkaFetchRecord) task's doRun() call, the while loop is entered and consumer continues to poll for messages.
- Possible solutions are to:

  - replace the ExecutorService with ScheduledExecutor to schedule the task with delay
  - implement the suspendable interface and support suspend/resume feature. underlying kafka client library already supports suspend/resume feature.

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed in Camel Version 3.0.0 with [CAMEL-12765](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12765)

Try upgrading to camel 3.x